# Trying to find an old book maybe from the 70s with huge telepathic dogs in the story line

Tags: story-identification, novel

The protagonist was born on another planet where he grew up fighting for survival. The cover pictured the dogs at shoulder high to a man and looking like a St. Bernard. It might have been a Science Fiction Book Club edition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is probably *The Book of Skaith: The Adventures of Eric John Stark* by [Leigh Brackett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leigh_Brackett).  It was a selection of the Science Fiction Book Club for Fall 1976 with this cover by [Don Maitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Maitz).

[image: Cover]

This is an omnibus of three novels all set on the planet Skaith: *The Ginger Star*, *The Hounds of Skaith*, and *The Reavers of Skaith*.  [Eric John Stark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_John_Stark) is the main character of each novel.

[image: Another cover image]

Stark was raised by non-human savages on Mercury, where he developed an extremely strong will to survive in an extremely challenging environment.

Also on Skaith are the Hellhounds, large beasts taller than a man, who are capable of telepathically projecting overwhelming fear onto intruders.

Comment: It certainly fits with the protagonist "born on another planet where he grew up fighting for survival." :-)